# How to know that virgo server loaded all the bundles from the code

Tags: java, eclipse-virgo

Is there a way to know from the java code that the virgo server is finished loading all the bundles.

I have a code in one of the bundles (not the last one in the plan) that need to activate some logic when the server is up.